# Bash Shell Script Infinite loop log in script

Tags: sh, infinite-loop, login-script

Currently trying to write a script to display user logins and logout on a network. Current code is as follows:

```
echo "The current users are:"

who | awk '{print $1}' | sort > tempfile1
cp tempfile1 tempfile2
more tempfile1

while true
do
    who | awk '{print $1}' | sort > temp2
    cmp -s tempfile1 tempfile2

    case "$?" in

    0)
            echo "No user has logged in/out in the last 3 seconds."
            ;;

    1)
            user=`comm -23 tempfile1 tempfile2`
            file=`grep $user tempfile1 tempfile2 | cut -c 1-5`

            [ $file == "tempfile1" ]
                    echo "User "$user" has logged out."


            [ $file == "tempfile2" ];
                    echo "User "$user" has logged in."

            ;;
    esac
    rm tempfile1
    mv tempfile2 tempfile1
    sleep 3

done
```

Running the script i get the following:

```
The current users are:
No user has logged in/out in the last 3 seconds.
mv: cannot stat ‘tempfile2’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘tempfile1’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘tempfile2’: No such file or directory
```

I am fairly certain there is a syntax issues within this code somewhere, but I am blind. Have compared to other similiar examples of this type of script to no avail. If anyone can help point out how much of an idiot i am that would be super helpful. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the first time through the loop you `rm tempfile1` then `mv tempfile2`. When you get back to the top of the loop and do `cmp` you don't have both files.

Is `who | awk '{print $1}' | sort > temp2` supposed to be `who | awk '{print $1}' | sort > tempfile2` ? (`temp2` is never referenced anywhere else...)

Comment: i bloody knew, i made a stupid mistake haha. thanks for pointing it out.